# Ubuntu 12.04 can't install D-Link DWM-156 drivers

Tags: usb, usb-modem

When connected to Ubuntu 12.04 D-Link DWM-156 detects it as USB storage medium but not as modem. It explored data stick in Windows and copied files "`3g_modem_connect_DWM156_i386.deb`" & "`3g_modem_connect_DWM156_amd64.deb`" files in Ubuntu and tried to execute them but none of them run.
I am new in Ubuntu and don't know commands, kindly answer in simple words.

Answer (score 1):

If your Ubuntu is on 32 bits, open a Terminal (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), go in the folder where you saved `.deb` file (`cd <*folder_where_is_deb_file*>`) and run next command:

```
sudo dpkg -i 3g_modem_connect_DWM156_i386.deb
```

If Ubuntu is on 64 bits, run:

```
sudo dpkg -i 3g_modem_connect_DWM156_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

If we execute `sudo dpkg -i 3g_modem_connect_DWM156_i386.deb` the modem will be installed. But, we can't work with or configure the settings of D-Link DWM-156 and will not get its config window....